# how to change an existing website to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a html ,css , and javascript files, they all form a tiny little web app which is required for a homework for my web app course, part of my homework is to make a bootstrap version off the web i just made.

My question is how do I convert my code to bootstrap to make my web responsive? what tricks/shortcuts can I take?

Comment: No tricks, no shortcuts. to use a library you need to know what the library does for you. Read up on bootstrap, start using bootstrap classes to layout your HTML.

Comment: I'm working on a library that automatically adds automatically adds css classes to html files. It's a work in progress but anyone else can find it [here](https://github.com/4d11/csskrt-csskrt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read bootstrap documentation here: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

I'll recommend you to start by choosing what type of container your content will be using: normal one, or fluid (100% browser width). With this defined, you can start putting some responsive grid classes on your div's.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit [the bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/) you'll be able to see exactly what Bootstrap can offer you, there is no translator which will automatically change your site for you.

Its just a case of applying the bootstrap component classes to your existing markup.  It shouldn't be too hard to achieve a replica of your site in Bootstrap if you read through the documentation.